# Manually pass list of strings to pipe

Tags: bash

If a command returns a list of strings I can pipe it to another command.

For instance:

```
command1 | command2
```

Lets say `command1` returns 2 lines.  Is there a way to do the same thing on the command line without a command that generates the lines?

I know this below doesn't work but maybe explains better what I mean:

```
("string 1", "string 2) | command2
```

I want to manually specify 2 lines to send into the pipe instead of using a command to generate them.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you thought of using `echo`?

Comment: I tried using echo with `\n` to separate strings but it just echod the `\n` back at me

Comment: Did you think of using *two* echo commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `echo` commands:

```
{ echo "string 1"; echo "string 2"; } | command2
```

or `printf` to do it with one command:

```
printf 'string 1\nstring 2\n' | command2
```

But if it's many lines, a here-doc is usually easier:

```
command2 <<EOF
string 1
string 2
EOF
```

Comment: Can also use printf like `printf "%s\n" "string 1" "string 2"` since printf will "loop" until all the arguments have been consumed by the format string.